# how to write a long equation in a 2 column format paper

Tags: equations, align

I wanna write a long equation in for a 2-column template of a paper. I used the `aligned` command to do that, but it doesn't work.

I attache the target equation I am trying to obtain.

[image]

Here is my try:

```
 \begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
 L ( \mathbf { m } ) = & k \exp \left( - \frac { 1 } { 2 } ( \mathbf { g } ( \mathbf { m } ) - \mathbf { d } _ { \mathrm { obs } } - \mathbf { d } _ { D } ) ^ { t } \mathbf { C } _ { D } ^ { - 1 }  ( \mathbf { g } ( \mathbf { m } ) \\  
 & - \mathbf { d } _ { \mathrm { obs } } - \mathbf { d } _ { D })\right)
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `\left( \right)` pair is split over two lines. Either add some dummy closing and opening macros `\right.` and `\left.` at the end and start of the line or manually choose the size (I'd recommend the later because automatically resizes brackets are often wrong)

## Dummy macros:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

 \begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
 L ( \mathbf { m } ) = 
    & k \exp \left( - \frac { 1 } { 2 } ( \mathbf { g } ( \mathbf { m } ) - \mathbf { d } _ { \mathrm { obs } } - \mathbf { d } _ { D } ) ^ { t } \mathbf { C } _ { D } ^ { - 1 }  ( \mathbf { g } ( \mathbf { m } ) \right. \\  
    & \left. - \mathbf { d } _ { \mathrm { obs } } - \mathbf { d } _ { D }) \vphantom{\frac { 1 } { 2 }} \right)
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

## Manual size:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

 \begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
 L ( \mathbf { m } ) = 
    & k \exp \biggl( - \frac { 1 } { 2 } ( \mathbf { g } ( \mathbf { m } ) - \mathbf { d } _ { \mathrm { obs } } - \mathbf { d } _ { D } ) ^ { t } \mathbf { C } _ { D } ^ { - 1 }  ( \mathbf { g } ( \mathbf { m } )  \\  
    & - \mathbf { d } _ { \mathrm { obs } } - \mathbf { d } _ { D })\biggr)
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

i would rewrite your equation in the following more compact (and meaningful) form:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
 \begin{equation}
 L(\mathbf{m}) =
    k \exp\Bigl(- \tfrac{1}{2}\bigl(\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{m}\bigr)^{t}
        \mathbf{C}_{D}^{-1}\bigl(\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{m}\bigr)\Bigr)
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{m}) =
       \mathbf{g}(\mathbf{m}) - \mathbf{d}_{\mathrm{obs}} - \mathbf{d}_{D}$.

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two variants, one with a different alignment, the other with `multline`. I used the medium-sized fraction command for the fractional coefficient, as I think it looks better than the full `\displaystyle`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]
 \begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
 L (\mathbf {m}) =
 k \exp \Bigl(&\medmath{-\frac {1} {2}}\bigl(\mathbf {g}(\mathbf {m}) - \mathbf {d}_{ \mathrm {obs}} - \mathbf {d}_{D} \bigr)^{\!t}\cdot \\%
 &\mathbf{C}_{D}^{-1} \bigl(\mathbf{g}(\mathbf{m}) - \mathbf{d} _{\mathrm{obs}} - \mathbf{d}_{D}\bigr) \Bigr)
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[13]
\begin{multline}
 L (\mathbf {m}) =
 k \exp \Bigl( \medmath{-\frac {1} {2}}\bigl(\mathbf {g} (\mathbf {m}) - \mathbf {d}_{ \mathrm {obs}} - \mathbf {d}_{D} \bigr)^{\!t}\cdot \\%
 \mathbf {C}_{D}^{- 1} \bigl(\mathbf{g} (\mathbf{m}) - \mathbf{d}_{\mathrm{obs}} - \mathbf {d}_{D}\bigr)\Bigr)
 \end{multline}

\end{document}
```

[image]